# Remove record by id from store in extJs/ Sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I Want to Remove record by Id.
Eg. store contains RoleId, RoleName fieds.

there are many records in store, I have RoleId to remove/delete record from store.
belove code I already tried but not working.. can you give me some suggestions for this.

```
  roleId = Ext.getStore('userStore').first().data.roleId;
                    var roleStore = Ext.getStore('userStore').first().companies().first().roles();
                    roleStore.remove(roleStore.findRecord('roleId', roleId));
```

And also tried...

```
  roleId = Ext.getStore('userStore').first().data.roleId;
                    var roleStore = Ext.getStore('userStore').first().companies().first().roles();
                    roleStore.removeAt(roleStore.find('roleId', roleId));
```

Comment: First thing is that a buffered store ? because buffered store doesnt support this method. If it is normal store then do you get valid result for "roleStore.find('roleId', roleId)" ?

Comment: is roleId int or string ? if it is integer, try to use parseInt to be sure the comparison is satisfied. As far is i remember, sencha use === in find method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly try this,

```
roleId = Ext.getStore('userStore').first().data.roleId;
var roleStoreItems = Ext.getStore('userStore').first().companies().first().roles().data.items;
roleStoreItems.forEach( function(item,index){
if(item.data.roleId==roleId){
roleStoreItems.remove(index);
}
});
```